# Run VSTS build task to run "npm build" only if files in a subdirectory has been changed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a big ASP.NET Core project and a subdirectory which has an Angular 5 project.

The current VSTS build process takes about 20 minutes, and the `npm install` and `angular build --prod` are taking the longest time.

And, when I push something NOT RELATED to Angular, the build process will build everything again including the Angular project.

I'm thinking of two options:

- Having a separated Angular build definition with a trigger for file changing in Angular dir.
- Or having a smart condition in npm tasks that can know if something changed in Angular **(And here is my question)**
- (or any other suggestions :D )

Comment: Separate build definition is the better way. On the other hand, you can use [npm-cache-install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-cache-install) to reduce the time of npm install if you are using private agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By something related, you mean whenever you make a change in your ASP.NET Core project?

If that is indeed the case, two build defintions should be setup for the Angular project and the .NET Core project. Both can have the trigger to build on check in and it will only build that certain set of files

If you want an integration build that creates a single artifact for release, you can setup a third build definition that you can trigger manually